# C# ASP redirects to ~/Account/Login for some reason - when the user is authenticated

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, model-view-controller, ntlm-authentication

I recently updated my C# asp project from framework v4.5 to v4.8, and also updated the referenced nuget packages. It is a webdav project to let the users browse our sql DB using the webdav style. Before the update it all was ok and worked like a charm.

Now I can see that accessing the web project I got 401 unauthorized errors using ntlm auth. Something redirects me to the ~/Account/Login page for some reason - nor on the IIS side the Basic and Windows auths are enabled only (forms and anonymus are disabled).

I tried to access the web with curl. Using BASIC auth it worked, but using ntlm it does not - got 401 and a small html body with the message starting with

> Object moved

In my web config (the interesting parts) are the following:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxUrlLength="8192" maxQueryStringLength="2048" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="Bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add verb="*" path="*" name="WebDavHandler" type="WebDavHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

In my WebDavHandler.cs file in the public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) method I see on the "context" that the request "IsAuthenticated=true", in the LogonUserIdentity I see the it is NTML auth, I can see the user login name and all, but the context.Request.Path already set to Account/Login.

I cannot find any reason which layer or setting is the reason of such a behaviour. Could somebody give me a help where to find the root cause?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are two part you need to check log. First is IIS, you can use failed request tracing to troubleshoot authentication module. Second is application itself, set a method to log its behavior.

Comment: In the IIS log I can see a 401 rejected line, with no user information in it. 2nd: when tHe 'method' starts - the request path is wrong. Where and how to log?